# Checkout cart suddenly is not working anymore

Tags: magento2, checkout, server-setup, debug

In the middle of the day after 2 months without deploying anything, my Magento 2 cart is not working, everyone that tries to go to the cart account sees an **error 500**, my server said it's probably a module since they aren't able to see anything weird from their side.

These are the issues that I got in my logs.

[image: Magento Checkout Cart is not working anymore]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running a full reindex. Reindex command is:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```